# How to map OneToMany relationship from Superclass

Tags: jpa, superclass

Hello! Recently I was stuck with such problem, and I hope the solution I provide below will help some other JPA newbies like me. If there is better solution please post it here!

The problem is as follows:

I want to create **OneToMany** relationship from classes `Book` and `CD` to class `Tag`.
In order to unify all the logic regarding class `Tag` from `Book` and `CD` I create **@MappedSuperclass** class `Item`, and make `Book` and `CD` descendants of class `Item`. But when I try to map 
`List <Tag>`
tags with **@OneToMany”**  in that superclass I get nothing good..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

In order to do an ORM mapping one should understand first what he actually wants to see in the database. So when I realized that reasonable solution is to create several transition tables between descendants of `Item` and `Tag`, I understood, that this may be accomplished using **@ManyToMany**. And it works fine!
 
Listing below.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Item extends Model {
    @Id
    public  Long id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Tag> tags;
    public String name;
    <…> }    
@Entity
public class Book extends Item {
    public int pageNum;
    <…> }
@Entity
public class CD extends Item{
    public int size;
    <…> }
@Entity
public class Tag extends Model{
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String text;
    <…> }
```

***PS** I'd post also class and er diagrams, but currently I got no r8n to post images.*